# error with "WITH DATA UNIQUE PRIMARY INDEX" in proc sql (from teradata)

Tags: sas, unique, teradata

I am using SAS to retrieve data via connection to TeraData (the original code was written in TeraData and copied to SAS platform as such. But I am getting the following error:

```
 **) WITH DATA UNIQUE PRIMARY INDEX (x_account_number)
                  ____
                  22
                  76
ERROR 22-322: Syntax error, expecting one of the following: ;, (, ',', ANSIMISS, CROSS, EXCEPT, FULL, GROUP, HAVING, INNER, 
              INTERSECT, JOIN, LEFT, NATURAL, NOMISS, ORDER, OUTER, RIGHT, UNION, WHERE.**
```

**This is my code:**

```
PROC SQL ;
CONNECT TO teradata AS ConDbms (MODE=teradata) ;
CREATE TABLE Step_1 AS                             
SELECT *
FROM Connection to ConDbms
(
    SELECT Account_Id,
           Customer_Id
    FROM T0101_Customer_Account_Relat 
    WHERE Cust_Acct_Relat_Type_Code = 101 
    AND Cancellation_Date > Date 
    AND account_id NOT IN (SELECT account_id 
                           FROM T0100_Account 
                           WHERE Account_Close_Date < DATE)

)WITH DATA UNIQUE PRIMARY INDEX (Account_Id, Customer_Id)

DISCONNECT FROM ConDbms ;
QUIT ;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is database-specific SQL not recognized by SAS parser, so could use SAS EXECUTE statement to create the table Step_1 in Teradata:

```
PROC SQL ;
CONNECT TO teradata AS ConDbms (MODE=teradata) ;
EXECUTE( CREATE TABLE Step_1 AS
  ( SELECT Account_Id, Customer_Id FROM T0101_Customer_Account_Relat
    WHERE Cust_Acct_Relat_Type_Code = 101 AND Cancellation_Date > Date
    AND account_id NOT IN (
      SELECT account_id FROM T0100_Account WHERE Account_Close_Date < DATE)
  ) WITH DATA UNIQUE PRIMARY INDEX (Account_Id, Customer_Id)
 ) BY ConDbms;
DISCONNECT FROM ConDbms ; 
QUIT ;
```

Or to create Step_1 as a SAS table, don't use the Teradata-specific DDL clause

```
PROC SQL ;
CONNECT TO teradata AS ConDbms (MODE=teradata) ;
CREATE TABLE Step_1 AS                             
SELECT *
FROM Connection to ConDbms
(
    SELECT Account_Id,
           Customer_Id
    FROM T0101_Customer_Account_Relat 
    WHERE Cust_Acct_Relat_Type_Code = 101 
    AND Cancellation_Date > Date 
    AND account_id NOT IN (SELECT account_id 
                           FROM T0100_Account 
                           WHERE Account_Close_Date < DATE)

);

DISCONNECT FROM ConDbms ;
QUIT ;
```